how to config the vscode-server start command with parameters "kill_on_drop: true" in a remote run?
In use of remote ssh, it auto (instalsl and) runs vscode-server on remote, with the following command
[04:34:15.096] [server] Starting server with command... Command { std: "/home/user/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-384ff7382de624fb94dbaf6da11977bba1ecd427/server/bin/code-server" "--connection-token=remotessh" "--accept-server-license-terms" "--start-server" "--enable-remote-auto-shutdown" "--socket-path=/tmp/code-e7ea3727-1fbd-4e37-ba55-02d172d08238", kill_on_drop: false }
I noticed that there is a parameter kill_on_drop: false, I can't find any docs about it but Chatgpt told me this is to kill the server when ssh connection drops. So it is exactly what I need and I need to set it to be kill_on_drop: true, because the vscode-server many times take a lot of cpu and ram that I can't even ssh to it, and it keeps running would not stop I can't even kill it easily.
I understand vscode-server does require resource when openning big folder and uses extensions and I have optimized that. Here what I want is to enable the kill_on_drop flag, cann't find any info on github of vscode or remote development repos. Please help.
